# import Statsmodels issue

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have the latest Anaconda distribution and running Jupyter notebooks 6.0.2 with Python 3.7.
I am trying to import statsmodels and I am getting the following error.

I have done the 
pip install statmodels

```
import statsmodels.api as sm 
or
import statmodels
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-2fcb280597c8> in <module>
----> 1 import statmodels.api

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statmodels'
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Doing the following worked for me.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels
```